# Linux-x86_64 Error: 12: Cannot allocate memory | ORA-27102: out of memory during transacctions

Tags: oracle

i actually have 2 Oracle linux 7 servers with Oracle RAC running on it, but sometimes i got ORA-27102: out of memory during transacctions altougth i have around 25GB free memory and physical Memory 128GB

shmmax: 4398046511104
shmmni: 4096
shmall: 1073741824

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
```

Mem:         128815       49772       21275       46708       57767       31767
Swap:         20479           0       20479

I dont know what is wrong any advice?

Thank you very much,

Kind regards!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try Below steps.

1. ```
   SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 "Used Megabytes", SUM(maxbytes)/1024/1024 "Max Megabytes" FROM dba_data_files WHERE tablespace_name IN ('SYSTEM') GROUP BY tablespace_name;
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT tablespace_name, file_name FROM dba_data_files WHERE tablespace_name IN ('SYSTEM');
   ```
3. ```
   ALTER TABLESPACE SYSTEM ADD DATAFILE '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE/system1.dbf' SIZE 600M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 512K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the unwanted cache data. Rebooting the server solves the issue also confirm that the value in `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` is 1. After rebooting, restart all the services including oracle.

```sh
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
reboot
```